# How can I slide a tableview left/right to acces another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, storyboard

How can I slide a tableview left/right to acces another view like the UIPageIndicator?
Can it be (Mainly) done in storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at UIPageControl. Check out the following sample code from apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795